# How can any thread signal for release of a binary semaphore

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, locking, mutex, semaphore

I am new to multithreading paradigm. While learning concurrency, every source I found says:

> "The difference between mutex and binary semaphore is the ownership
>   i.e. a mutex can be signaled for release by only the thread who
>   created it while a semaphore can be signaled any thread"

Considering a scenario where thread A has acquired a binary semaphore lock on resource x and processing it. If any thread can call a release signal for lock on x, doesn't this open a possibility of any thread calling a release on the lock amidst the time when thread A was using x.

Isn't there a scope of inconsistency in this or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, if threads are arbitrarily acquiring or releasing a semaphore, the result would be disastrous and the fact, that implementations do not prevent this, does not imply that this is a useful scenario.

However, there might be real use cases if the involved threads use another mechanism to coordinate themselves while using the semaphore to hold these threads off which do not participate in these coordination.

Imagine you expand a use case where one thread acquires the semaphore for performing a task to parallel execution of said task. After acquiring the semaphore, several worker threads are spawned, each of them working on a different part of the data, thus naturally working non-interfering. Then the *last* worker thread releases the semaphore which elides the need for another communication between the initiating thread and the worker threads. Of course, this requires the worker thread to detect whether it is the last one, but a simple atomic integer holding the number of active workers would be sufficient.

Comment: Doesn't such use of semaphore lead to a room for another overhead in which we are using yet another technique to now prevent consistency? Isn't this the primary reason for which semaphores where first created? (to retain consistency using synchronization )

Comment: The reason for using such more complicated solution instead of the simple one is the same as for why we use multiple distinct semaphores or locks instead of one global lock for everything (or why we use multi-threading at all). The simple solution isn’t always satisfactory. However, you shouldn’t raise the complexity of a program without having an actual problem to solve, that’s right.